# How to access the attribute table of a TIF map in R?

Tags: r, attributes, tiff, raster

I [downloaded a map](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cvtrj35w6hzehhb/AAC39W-8PcO8lExFiJRKd0XMa/MalhaFundiaria_LandTenure/BD_MalhaFundiaria_DB_LandTenure?dl=0) in TIF format that came with the following files: a2_LOt_12.tif.vat.cpg; a2_LOt_12_v170321.tfw; a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif; a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif.aux; a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif.ovr a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif.vat.dbf; a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif (XML doc). In ArcGIS the file opens fine and I can access the attribute table:

[image]

However, I am having a tough time opening that table in R. I expected "levels()" to work, but it returns "NULL":

```
r <- raster("a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif")
levels(r)
```

Is there another way to access that attribute table in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Arc prefers to store the RAT in a separate file rather than in the tif where it is expected. You should be able to do something like this

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif")

library(foreign)
rat <- read.dbf("a2_LOt_12_v170321.tif.vat.dbf")

colnames(rat)[1] <- "ID"
levels(r) <- rat
```